# What are the measurable benefits from migrating from Flex 3 to Flex 4?

Tags: flex4, flex3, upgrade, flex-spark

We have a big Flex 3 project with 30 developers. I need to present benefits/costs of upgrading from Flex 3 to Flex 4 and I can't seem to find existing data on Google. I assume I am not the first to do this. Our application is RIA app so it's not a video/custom component heavy.

I have these benefits:
1) Right to left native support
2) Smooth Scrolling
3) Two way binding
4) FXG
5) Better state model

I need more data about the following:
1) Spark - What are the actual benefit from Spark components? Are they faster? How much faster compared to halo? easier to use?
2) It mentions [Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4sdk_whatsnew.html) and in many articles that Flex 4 has compile speed improvements. Are there any benchmarks?
I see  [Here](http://www.joshuaostrom.com/2008/11/21/flex-4-gumbo-compiler-benchmark/) a 60% increase, but not sure if it's the SDK version with Flex 3 compatibility or not.

If anyone here already wrote a report like this, or has upgraded and can report real benefits or other ideas, please share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your project.

---

Do you need better data validation / custom formatters?

Do you update your design often?

Are you in need of not trivial layouts?

Would you like to use Globalization API introduced in Flash Player 10.1?

Are you ready to acknowledge that nobody will ever fix existing open issues at Halo mx components set?

Comment: 1) Yes. Is there improvements in data validation?<br>
2) Design is not updated often<br>
3) No need for no trivial layouts. Perhaps for better custom controls.<br>
4) Just saw the Globalization API. Will this only be accessible with Flex 4? if so this is a big selling point<br>
5) This is very good point. I'll add it to my list

Comment: 1) Yes, there are. For example, Spark Form supports the display of multiple data field errors without single tooltip.  Spark Formatters http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+Formatters will format currency, date and number values in so much better fashion.  3) How about Spark List with zoom effect? ;) http://flexwiz.amosl.com/flex/spark-list-with-zoom-effect/

Answer (score 0):

Cost: Flex 4 needs Flash Player 10

This stopped us from using it yet - our requirements are to support Flash Player 9 and up

Comment: We don't have such a requirement, so I am looking for more benefits

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2010/3/21/Flex-3-to-Flex-4-Migration-Howto

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FeaturesAndMigration/flex_4_features.pdf

you can try these links..